# How to access the row property of a shape in a collection?

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I have a collection of shapes in `allShpsColl` and I need to test if each shape resides in a group of rows called swimlanes here.

```
For i = 1 To swimlaneCount
    For j = 1 To allShpsColl.count
        If GetSwimlaneNum(allShpsColl.Item(j).Row) = i Then '<--Object doesn't support this property or method
            shpCount = shpCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve rowShpsArr(1 To shpCount)
            rowShpsArr(shpCount) = allShpsColl.Item(j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

And the `GetSwimlaneNum` function is:

```
Function GetSwimlaneNum(ByRef lowRow As Integer) As Integer

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 999
    If lowRow > (i - 1) * 9 And lowRow <= i * 9 Then
        GetSwimlaneNum = i
        Exit For
    End If

Next i End Function
```

How can I access the row property of the corresponding collection item so that I can  compare values?

Comment: Try `.TopLeftCell.Row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `TopLeftCell` represents the cell that lies under the upper-left corner of the shape object.

```vb
If GetSwimlaneNum(allShpsColl.Item(j).TopLeftCell.Row) = i Then
```

---

- If the shape may cover multiple lanes, you need two conditions to ensure that the shape is `within` a lane.

```vb
    If GetSwimlaneNum(allShpsColl.Item(j).TopLeftCell.Row) = i And _
       GetSwimlaneNum(allShpsColl.Item(j).BottomRightCell.Row) = i Then
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Shape.BottomRightCell property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.bottomrightcell?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Shape.TopLeftCell property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.topleftcell?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)